# referral by company's product specific and company specific

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am thinking of creating a referral and reward app where a user will list his/her company with the product they have. A company can use referral program by product specific or just in whole(could not name it properly). For example, I have listed my company called `ABC Company` and I have a product like smartphone, smart Tvs, Laptops. I would like to market for my company by just saying refer me to 10 people and get something in return(this is non-product specific) or I should be able to market my specific product let's say when user goes to the `abc phone XI` and there will be refer this phone and get the same phone in return if you refer to more than 50 or if more than 10 then 10% discount etc. This is just an example to demonstrate my project.

For now I created the model for `Company, Product(with nested category), referral`. But I have no idea on how should i be able to keep the referral based on above example like product specific or based on full company.

Here is what I have done

```
class Product(models.Model):
    """
    product model
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = TreeForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='/company/', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    stocks = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)


class Company(models.Model):
    """
    company model
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)
    domain = models.URLField(blank=False, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    pan_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    industry = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=False)

class Join(models.Model):
    """
    Join Model
    """
    email = models.EmailField()
    friend = models.ForeignKey("self", related_name='referral', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='ABC', unique=True)
    count_added = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, related_name='count', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='ABC')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.email)
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly. I suggest you to use `django-activity-stream` and then track your website activity by stream.

Comment: @Sarit it says its an activity follow and unfollow package. My case is, a company owner should be able to use referral for his/her specific products or non-specific referral but it should belong to that company. The main thing is, I wanted to start this without using such package and not even rest-auth related package so I can understand the inner part of django. It is just for my understanding. Can you help me at this by giving me some idea on model part, please?